# I want to auto increment queue in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying below code but the queue is not incrementing automatically
after thread 1 is complete it should check for new worker count and queue them up, but here worker count is getting set once and all threads are completing the work up to workers count,

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use threads::shared;

$count = 5; 
sub process
          {
             print "proccess started";
             return $count --;
           }


sub getWorkItems 
               {  
                 $n =&process;
                 return $n--;
               }
print "******************worker_count*********************\n";
 print $n;


     sub worker {
                  my $tid = threads->tid;
                  my( $Qwork, $Qresults ) = @_;
                  while( my $work = $Qwork->dequeue ) 
                       {  
                          sub result 
                               { my $i = threads->tid; 
                                  print "\nhello \n";
                                  print  "$i";
                                  print "\n"
                                }
                         &result;
                     $Qresults->enqueue();
                  }
              }

our $THREADS = 1;

my $Qwork = new Thread::Queue;
my $Qresults = new Thread::Queue;


## Create the pool of workers
my @pool = map
{
    threads->create( \&worker, $Qwork, $Qresults )

} 1 .. $THREADS;

## Get the work items (from somewhere)
## and queue them up for the workers

while( my $workItem = getWorkItems()  ) 
    {
      $Qwork->enqueue( $workItem );
     }

$Qwork->enqueue( (undef) x $THREADS );

for ( 1 .. $THREADS ) 
    {

    while( $Qresults->dequeue ) 
         {
         ## Do something with the result ##
          print "Request_proccessed";
          }

    }

## Clean up the threads
$_->join for @pool;
```

output :::

hello 
1

hello 
1

hello 
1

hello 
1

hello 
1

Comment: Note: You should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2):

Before we start, let me mention that you should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`.

You have three major problems:

- You print `threads->tid`, but I think you mean to print `$work`.
- You have a named sub inside of another named sub. Never do that. There's no point in doing so —the inner sub isn't private to the outer sub— and it causes problems.
- You never add anything to `$Qresults`, but the main thread expects there to be at least one false value in it.

Fixed and cleaned up code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use threads;

use Thread::Queue 3.01;

use constant NUM_THREADS => 1;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   return $job*2;
}

{
   my $job_q    = Thread::Queue->new();
   my $result_q = Thread::Queue->new();

   my @threads =
      map {
         async {
            while (defined( my $job = $job_q->dequeue() )) {
               my $result = worker($job);
               $result_q->enqueue($result);
            }
         }
      }
         1..NUM_THREADS;

   # Add some jobs to the queue.
   my $num_jobs = 0;
   for my $job (1..5) {
      $job_q->enqueue($job);
      ++$num_jobs;
   }

   $job_q->end();

   # Collect the result of the jobs.
   for (1..$num_jobs) {
      my $result = $result_q->dequeue();
      say "Result: $result";
   }

   $_->join for @threads;
}
```

Note how the worker doesn't need to know anything about the queues or threads.

Comment: my $add_job_count = 10;
sub new_jobs 
{ 
   return $add_job_count -- ; 
}

   my $num_jobs = 0;
   while( my $job = new_jobs()) {
          $job_q->enqueue($job);
        ++$num_jobs;
   }

   $job_q->end();   

I am expecting the job to run 55 times 
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 55
but only working 10 time using same scripts

Comment: You only place 10 things in the queue, not 55

Comment: let say this way, in the beginning, there were 10 jobs in a queue, and 2 threads start processing them, in between processing I want to add 2 more jobs to the queue.

Comment: The code is already doing that. The thread(s) start processing as soon as there's a job available. The remaining jobs are added after the first job has (potentially) started. Jobs can be added as long as `->end` hasn't been called.